# Complexity of solving random underdetermined polynomial equations over finite fields

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-complexity, finite-fields, cryptography

Consider a random system of degree-$d$ polynomials, with $n$ variables and $m$ equations, over some finite field $\mathbb{F}_q:$
$$\begin{align}\sum_{\substack{(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \\ \alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n\le d}} &p^{(1)}_{\vec{\alpha}} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i} = 0,\\ &\vdots \\ \sum_{\substack{(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0} \\ \alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_n\le d}} &p^{(m)}_{\vec{\alpha}} \cdot \prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{\alpha_i} = 0.\end{align}$$
Here, a random system means that the coefficients $p^{(j)}_{\vec{\alpha}}$ are chosen uniformly at random from $\mathbb{F}_q$.

We may think of the degree $d$ as a constant. I am interested in algorithms solving these equations (i.e. finding a solution $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{F}_q^n$) in the *underdetermined* case, when $m \ll n$.

**Prior works:** when $d=2$, it is known that when $n = \Omega(m^{\,2})$, such systems can be solved in *polynomial* time (see [this paper (Section 7)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_15.pdf) for fields of even characteristic, and [this paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-319-11659-4_3) for odd characteristic).

**Question:** what is the general complexity for $d \ge 3?$ More precisely, what is the smallest exponent $c=c(d) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there exists a polynomial-time algorithm when $n = \Omega(m^{\,c})$?

I don't have a good guess for this question. In particular, when trying to generalize the algorithms in the case $d=2$ to general $d$, the best I can get is $c=d!$, which doesn't seem like the right answer.